# Rails/SQL: Find which belongs to all, not any

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

For example, I'v got simple app with Post model and Tag model. They associated with each other as has-many. I need to find Posts, which are associated with any number of tags.
For example, I want to find all Posts, which are tagged with "Cat" and "Forest" tags, but not which are tagged with "Forest" OR "Cat". So, only cat's in the forest.

How can I run such query in Rails or in a raw SQL? If I use IN operator on associated model, like

```
PostTag.where(tag_id: [1,2])
```

I will get Post's with any of this two tags, but I need intersection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one stab would be to do something like the following:

```
post_tag_ids = PostTag.joins(:tags).where('tags.id = 1').pluck(:id) & PostTag.joins(:tags).where('tags.id = 2').pluck(:id)
post_tags = PostTag.find(post_tag_ids)
```

OR better yet

```
(PostTag.joins(:tags).where('tags.id = 1') & PostTag.joins(:tags).where('tags.id = 2')).uniq
```

So you are first finding the post_tag ids of post with tag 1 then tag 2, then getting the intersection of the two sets, and querying for those.

Most of the time, people try to accomplish a task with a one liner in rails, when the simplest way might be right under their noses. This does however result in 3 queries however, so keep that in mind. If i was to do this in sql, it would be the same thing using subqueries however.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear. I thought may be there a better solution, instead of firing N queries.

Comment: I cut out a query, see above